# Running Jira in docker and hosting it on localhost

Tags: docker, localhost, jira

I followed the following steps to run the jira in my docker desktop from this URl ([Documentation link](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-software)):

[image: Steps I followed]

My docker Jira container runs fine but when I visit my localhost I see an error. Please find these screenshots:

[image: Docker Desktop]

Error:
[image: Error]

What am I be missing here? Thank you.

Comment: The documentation tells you '-p 8080:8080', but you've done '-p 3000:8080'. Why?

Comment: @DavidBakkers My 8080 port is already occupied. I have tried with 8080 as well. Faced Same issue.

Comment: Is Docker running on the same computer as the web browser you're trying to connect with?